# Use current month/day in datetime parse

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I'm trying to parse a string that is just '07:43 PM'. I figured out the `strptime()` function but when I print the result the day, month and year are all wrong. It's not using the current time, it uses 1, 1 and 1900 respectively. A naive solution to this I found would be to just use `.replace()` and replace the day, month and year with the current values. Is there something else I can do?

```
y = '07:43 PM'
print(datetime.strptime(y, '%I:%M %p'))  #1900-01-01 19:43:00
```

Comment: When you are parsing this string, do you ALWAYS want to use the current day? If so, use datetime.now() as a base and replace the hour and minute.

Comment: Yes I do always want the current day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment said you can get the `now` time then update those fields with what you want such as:

```
from datetime import datetime
y = '07:43 PM'
now, stripped = datetime.now(), datetime.strptime(y, '%I:%M %p')
now = now.replace(hour=stripped.hour, minute=stripped.minute)
print(now)
```